# The tkinter .get metho d is not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make a formula calculator for a school project. I am trying to use the .get tkinter method to get what is in an Entry. It always sends an error. I don't want to write it into a class though.

This is not the final code.

```
from tkinter import *

def speedCalc():
    _distance = spDistance.get()
    _time = spTime.get()

spDistance = Entry(speed).grid(row=1, column=1)
spTime = Entry(speed).grid(row=2, column=1)
spSpeed = Entry(speed).grid(row=3, column=1)

spConvert = Button(speed, text="Calculate", command=speedCalc)
spConvert.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

When I execute the code, it says this on the console:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"C:\Users\JackP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/JackP/Desktop/Python Projets/Formula App/4. Extention.py", line 25, in speedCalc
_distance = spDistance.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: This question has been asked countless times. please just google [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=AttributeError%3A+%27NoneType%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27get%27&oq=AttributeError%3A+%27NoneType%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27get%27&gs_l=psy-ab.3...325.325.0.634.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.h1eEyi4YuD0) and you would have your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I searched around for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a layout like `grid` or `pack` on the same line as the initialization. You have to put those on separate lines:

```
spDistance = Entry(speed)
spDistance.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking around for this for ages because I created a text editor. I think I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a widget to a variable, do not call a layout manager method on the widget directly on the same line; do it on another line.
The reason is that thinter layout managers `pack`, `grid` and `place` return `None`

```
from tkinter import *

def speedCalc():
    _distance = spDistance.get()
    _time = spTime.get()

spDistance = Entry(speed)
spDistance.grid(row=1, column=1)
spTime = Entry(speed)
spTime.grid(row=2, column=1)
spSpeed = Entry(speed)
spSpeed.grid(row=3, column=1)

spConvert = Button(speed, text="Calculate", command=speedCalc)
spConvert.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't search for the error, I just searched for "tkinter .get not working.".